# Is operator-> guaranteed to work for iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading, std

I read something from "More Effective C++", item 18:

> In brief, the iterator it is an object, not a pointer, so there is no guarantee that “->” can be applied to it.† The STL does require that “.” and “*” be valid for iterators, however, so (*it).second, though syntactically clumsy, is guaranteed to work.)

Usually, I use `->` on iterators and there isn't any problem. Could anyone give a example or explain it?

Comment: Did you read footnote 6 ?

Comment: you mean the book? I don't see a footnote or there is something wrong with mine

Comment: It looks like it's a `†` rather than a `6` in your version.

Comment: oh I find it ,thank you.  it's my careless.

Comment: Usually it doesn't matter what the STL requires. What matters is what is specified in the C++ standard.

Comment: How to find it? read the c++ standard mannal ?

Comment: the book was suggesting some old compiler doesn't support `operator->`

Comment: It should not be a problem now (not with STL iterators).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning how to look for footnotes in a book

Answer (score 12):

"More Effective C++" is nearly 20 years old (published 1996); while an excellent book, it should be read with an awareness of its historical context.

In the 2003 version of the Standard (itself over 10 years old) iterators are required to support `->` (**[lib.iterator.requirements]**/1):

> [...] All iterators `i` for which the expression `(*i).m` is well-defined, support the expression `i->m` with the same semantics as `(*i).m.` [...]

You would only need to write `(*i).m` when working with an archaic implementation with non-compliant "standard" libraries.